# Building OR WHERE programmatically in Peewee

Tags: python, where-clause, peewee

I have a list of keywords with an unknown number of elements like:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

I need to build a query using Peewee where a column name need to be %LIKE%
either one of the words in the list.

SQL example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t 
WHERE name LIKE '%key1%' OR 
name LIKE '%key2%' OR
name LIKE '%key3%'
```

On the documentation it looks like I can build the query like so:

```
T.select().where(T.name ** 'key1' | T.name ** 'key2' | T.name ** 'key3')
```

This does not look can be built programmatically though...

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reduce and the "or_" operator from the standard library:

```
clauses = [
    (T.name ** 'key1'),
    (T.name ** 'key2'),
    (T.name ** 'key3')]
expr = reduce(operator.or_, clauses)
query = T.select().where(expr)
```

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks!

Comment: side effect: you get a big mess of parenthesis but hopefully it won't affect the speed.